# How to get array of objects based on object and array list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, arrayobject

I have an array of object,  a object, and an arraylist.

I have to  get the array of objects based on conditions using javascript:

1. Fetch the array of objects if the `value` property matches with object `item`
2. Check if the `code` value exists in the arraylist `arraylist`, if exists return array ibject
3. Else return empty

```js
var arrobj1 =[
  {id:1, name: zen, code: "SP", value: 100},
  {id:2, name: abi, code: "IN", value: 200},
  {id:3, name: lisa, code: "SG", value: 200}
]
var arraylist =["IN"]
var obj1={
  id:34, code: "SP", country: "mexico", item: 200
}
```

Expected Output:

// value & item matches, code does not exists so empty
[]

```js
var arrobj2 =[
  {id:1, name: zen, code: "SP", value: 300},
  {id:2, name: abi, code: "SP", value: 200},
  {id:3, name: lisa, code: "SG", value: 100}
]
var arraylist =["IN"]
var obj2={
  id:34, code: "SP", country: "italy", item: 100
}
```

Expected Output

// value & item matches, code matches

```
[
    {id:3, name: lisa, code: "SG", value: 100}
]
```

I have tried using below code:

```js
var result = arrobj1.some(e => {
        if (e.value === obj.item &&
          (arraylist.includes(e.code)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
```

Comment: Just return (e.value === obj.item && (arraylist.includes(e.code) instead of false or true? Also 'some' returns a boolean.

Comment: If I understand the task correctly, there should be `value matches, code DOES exist` in the first comment.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what you meant by `fetch the array of objects if the value property matches with object item`. Do you mean filter all the objects with value that matches with the `obj.item`?

Comment: @BikramKarki thanks for reply,  `arrobj property `value` matches with obj.item, and have code DOES exist with arraylist`

Comment: In that case, does @user14967413's suggestion answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

First `filter` items, then use `some`.

```
let filtered = arrobj1.filter(({value}) => value == obj1.item)
let result = filtered.some(({code}) => arraylist.includes(code)) ? [] : filtered
```